# Jquery .click on checkbox with bootstrap not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I create a code in my html:
`<input type="checkbox" name="field_opt2" value="true" checked="" style="">`

but when I run it in the browser it will look like this:

```
<div class="icheckbox_square-green checked" style="position: relative;">
<input type="checkbox" name="field_opt2" value="true" checked="" style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">
<ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; opacity: 0; background: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
</ins>
</div>
```

and my jquery script is not working:

```
$(".early-bird-check").click(function(){
            alert("Asdsd");
        });
```

any idea please?

Comment: Anything in console log.?

Comment: Well I can't see you using the class `.early-bird-check` anywhere in your input?

Comment: You don't use the attribute class="early-bird-check" in the html element

Comment: wrapped code in dom ready?

Comment: Yea where is the checker classed as early bird check ?

Comment: Works here : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/wonedpgx/1/ Added early bird class to the checkbox

Answer (score -1):

**early-bird-check** class is missing.you can also use click function with attributes e.g   $('input[name="field_opt2"]').click(function(){
   alert('hi')
});   .Please resend entire code if possible